# Swift - How To Convert ConstUnsafePointer<()> to CTRunRef

Tags: ios, swift

I intended to convert ConstUnsafePointer<()> to CTRunRef, but errors occur

```
var run: CTRunRef = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(runArray, runIndex) as CTRunRef
```

the complier said:
'ConstUnsafePointer<()>' is not convertible to 'CTRunRef'

Comment: Maybe you should use an `NSArray` instead

Comment: I use obj-c to write this code instead :(

Answer (score 1):

see like this

```
let runArray = ((CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line) as [AnyObject]) as! [CTRunRef])
for runIndex in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(runArray) {
    let run: CTRunRef = runArray[runIndex]
}
```